# Evitar ingreso en caso de que el usuario y contraseña ingresados no sean de un administrador

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

La siguiente sentencia es para preguntar si un usuario con la contraseña está registrada de acuerdo a un cargo, el cual debe ser administrador:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE rutfuncionario='"+usuario+"'and contrasena='"+pass+"'" ;
```

El formulario recibe dos datos del usuario, su contraseña y su rut.

Tengo 2 tablas:

tabla `usuario(rutfuncionar(pk) , nombrefuncionario,cargo,fechamodificacion ,contrasena)`

tabla `cargo (idcargo (pk) , nombrecargo)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es realmente la pregunta? Además, tu consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL: utiliza en su lugar [_sentencias preparadas_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: a muchas gracias , mi pregunta es la misma , como puedo hacer la consulta bien ya que quiero consultar si el usuario ingresado esta registrado con su rut , con su contraseña y si tiene cargo administrador , si no es administrador que no pueda ingresar , te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Dale un título específico a tu pregunta: recordá que [es.so] __no es un foro__. Por lo demás, la estructura de tus tablas es importante, además de mostrar lo que has intentado. Eso que mencionaste en tu comentario no está en la pregunta :) Y por último: especificá en las etiquetas la base de datos que estás utilizando (no es SQL a secas, puede que sea MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server...)

Comment: bueno le agregare todo

Comment: Cuando trabajas con base de datos usa [consultas preparadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), respecto a tu pregunta vas a tener que realizar uso del join o de subconsultas para obtener el nombre del cargo debido a que se encuentra en otra tabla

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score 0):

Como te habían comentado, es mejor utilizar prepared statement.

En una sentencia simple para validar también el cargo según lo que solicitas, la sentencia sería la siguiente:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario u INNER JOIN cargo c ON c.idcargo = u.cargo WHERE rutfuncionario='"+usuario+"' and contrasena='"+pass+"' and c.nombrecargo = "'+nombrecargo+'";
```

La u después de usuario y la c después de cargo es un alias para la tabla.

Recuerda que el INNER JOIN se realiza después del FROM o de otros INNER JOINs (para especificar relaciones adicionales entre tablas).

La solución haciendo uso de PreparedStatement(la cual es mas segura) sería de la siguiente forma:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario u INNER JOIN cargo c ON c.idcargo = u.cargo WHERE rutfuncionario= ? and contrasena= ? and c.nombrecargo = ?";

PreparedStatement selUs = con.prepareStatement(sql);//se crea el objeto prepare Statement que devuelve el método prepareStatement() de tu conexión.
selUs.setInt(1,usuario); //en la primera posición de el '?', ingresa un Int (usuario) que es el ruc.
selUs.setString(2,pass); //En la segunda posición del '?' ingresa la contraseña (un String)
selUs.setString(3,nombrecargo); //En la tercera posición del '?' ingresa el nombrecargo que estás buscando (un String)

ResultSet rs = selUS.executeQuery(); //Ejecuta la consulta del preparedStatement y devuelve un ResultSet
```

Comment: hola , como seria si quiero agregarle el cargo?seria algpo asi ; String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE rutfuncionario='"+usuario+"' and contrasena='"+pass+"'and cargo=administrador'" ;

Comment: le escribi :  String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  rutfuncionario='"+usuario+"'and  contrasena='"+pass+"' and  INNER JOIN   cargo.nombrecargo=admin'";            estara bien<?

Comment: He modificado la respuesta según lo que solicitas y también usando PreparedStatement. Espero haber respondido a tu duda.